# Why isn't it possible to change the node pool _name_?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

As far as I can tell, the *name* of a node-pool is its *least* consequential aspect, so why isn't it possible to change it?

I came across this on GKE, but googling around, DigitalOcean has a similar limitation (recommended workaround is "*create new node-pool with the name you want, and migrate/drain to it*")

I found this aspect annoying recently, and was wondering whether there is a technical limitation here, or whether this is something that could easily be added on as a feature.

*Edit:*

One reason to ask this question here is that GKE Support [explicitly mentions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/getting-support) asking questions on StackOverflow with the `google-kubernetes-engine` tag as a means of having them answered.

Comment: I think you should ask this to GKE support team. 
Technically speaking a node pool is just a set of worker nodes sharing the same labels, annotations/taints/specifications, after the way platform providers lock their operational model is often based to how they provision the said platform.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons stated in my other comment

Comment: Fair enough, I only mentioned it here because it seemed to be a feature across two different clouds, and might point to some overlooked commonality.E.g. I know some behaviors originate from immutability concerns, but wasn't sure if this was one of them.

Comment: This is a product limitation and is confirmed on this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1054078/in-gcp-how-to-change-default-pool-name-while-creating-through-gcloud-cli). I would suggest to raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the link, makes sense. Will close out this question.